# Function to highlight differences in two columns of a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing employee data utilizing a dataframe in Pandas. The raw data is produced into excel files from our system. I have reduced the columns to what I want (pay settings) and then merged the dataframes so the old data is now next to the new data. This data is the same employee data, but just a week apart.

What I'm now trying to do is create a function that will look at 4 total columns and compare them. Compare "Old_Grade" vs "New_Grade" and compare "Old_Step" vs "New_Step". If either of these two columns aren't the same, I want to hightlight the value so it easily be seen if the grade and or step has changed from last weeks data.

I have been able to use a lambda function to compare either the old / new grade or the old/new step but I can't get them both to do it.  This is the lamda function that I use:

```
colored_changes1 = merged_changes.style.apply(lambda x: (x != merged_changes['Old_Grade']).map({True: 'background-color: yellow', False: ''}),subset=['New_Grade'])
```

[Above Lambda Function Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQjfZ.png)

I tried taking the colored_changes1 lamda function and then making a second lamba function using the Old Step / New Step columns with the results from colored_changes1 but it gives me a styler error.

In another attempt, I tried this function:

```
def highlight_differences(merged_changes, Old_Grade, New_Grade):
   
    def highlight_diff(value):
        if value[Old_Grade] != value[New_Grade]:
            return 'background-color: yellow'
        else:
            return ''

    return merged_changes.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=1)


highlighted_df = highlight_differences(merged_changes, 'Old_Grade', 'New_Grade')
highlighted_df.to_excel('highlighted_differences.xlsx', index=False)
```

This gives me a different error and says my dataframe is collapsing to a series because its only trying to return one value.

Is it possible to write a function that looks at two pay settings: Old_Grade vs New_Grade and Old_Step vs New_Step and then highlights the changes so I can quickly see when there is a change and where its located.

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a highlight function that returns a full dataframe of desired colors and use `df.style.apply` with `axis = None`.

```
def highlight(df):
    grade_mismatch = df['Old_Grade'] != df['New_Grade']
    step_mismatch = df['Old_Step'] != df['New_Step']
    
    color = df.copy()
    color.loc[:, :] = ''
    color.loc[grade_mismatch, 'New_Grade'] = 'background-color: yellow'
    color.loc[step_mismatch, 'New_Step'] = 'background-color: yellow'

    return color

df.style.apply(highlight, axis = None)
```

Comment: Would appreciate it if you mark this the accepted answer.

Comment: You got my upvote!  +1